# error 1066 while joining 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

Now have the following problem. I am trying to get data from 3 tables using the following query.

```
SELECT Message, Name
FROM message, users
LEFT JOIN user_message ON ID = Message_id
LEFT JOIN user_message ON ID = User_id
WHERE user_message.status = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

And here I am getting error 1066 what am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this SQL code give error 1066 (Not unique table/alias: 'user')?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435177/why-does-this-sql-code-give-error-1066-not-unique-table-alias-user)

Comment: You need to give aliases to the table (and fields), otherwise MySQL can't determine, for example, *which* `user_message.status` you're talking about. Moreover, the query has probably one JOIN too many. See Saharsh Shah's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.Message, u.Name
FROM message m
INNER JOIN user_message um ON m.ID = um.Message_id
INNER JOIN users u ON u.ID = um.User_id
WHERE um.status = 1
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give alias and try like this

```
SELECT t1.Message, t2.Name
FROM message as t1
LEFT JOIN user_message as t2 ON t2.ID = t1.Message_id 
LEFT JOIN users as t3. ON t3.ID = t2.User_id
WHERE t3.status = 1
LIMIT 0 , 30
```