# Why get I MySQL error 1066 on inner join?

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting a Error Code 1066.  Not unique table/alias `usps 75078` on this sql script:

```
UPDATE `20160318 flagdatabase`,
       `usps 75078`
INNER JOIN `usps 75078` ON `20160318 flagdatabase.Street` = `usps 75078.Street_Name`
SET `20160318 flagdatabase.Carrier_Route` = `usps 75078.Carrier_Route`
SET `20160318 flagdatabase.Zip4_Low_Add` = `usps 75078.Zip4_Low_Add`
SET `20160318 flagdatabase.Zip4_High_Add` = `usps 75078.Zip4_High_Address`
WHERE `20160318 flagdatabase.Street` = `usps 75078.Street_Name`
  AND `20160318 flagdatabase.HouseNumber` >= `usps 75078.Primary_Low_Address`
  AND `20160318 flagdatabase.HouseNumber` <= `usps 75078.Primary_High_Address`;
```

Comment: Looks like when JOINing a table to itself, you need to use two unique identifiers. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1435186/864233)

Comment: is `20160318` the database? if so then should it be: `20160318.flagdatabase`? You don't actually have spaces in your column / table names do you? That is going to make it interesting to read and maintain? Please add the table create statements to your question so I can understand what is really happening?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is very hard to read due to the (insane) use of dots and spaces in table names, so I'll paraphrase using placeholder names.

Your query looks like:

```
update t1, t2 join t2 on some condition
...
```

which lists t2 twice in the query. You must give (at least) one of the t2 references an *alias*, and use that alias instead of the table name throughout the query, like this:

```
update t1, t2 join t2 as t3 on some condition
...
```

Here I've used "t3" as the alias.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to fix your query, and leave it like this:

```
UPDATE `20160318 flagdatabase`,
INNER JOIN `usps 75078` ON `20160318 flagdatabase.Street` = `usps 75078.Street_Name`
SET `20160318 flagdatabase.Carrier_Route` = `usps 75078.Carrier_Route`, 
`20160318 flagdatabase.Zip4_Low_Add` = `usps 75078.Zip4_Low_Add`.
`20160318 flagdatabase.Zip4_High_Add` = `usps 75078.Zip4_High_Address`
WHERE `20160318 flagdatabase.Street` = `usps 75078.Street_Name`
  AND `20160318 flagdatabase.HouseNumber` >= `usps 75078.Primary_Low_Address`
  AND `20160318 flagdatabase.HouseNumber` <= `usps 75078.Primary_High_Address`;
```