# Why does this sql #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'categories'?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

```
SELECT
    categories.id, categories.name
AS
    parentName
FROM
    categories
INNER JOIN
    categories
ON
    categories.parent = categories.id
ORDER BY
    id
DESC
```

I want to inner join two columns in same table (categories).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this SQL code give error 1066 (Not unique table/alias: 'user')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435177/why-does-this-sql-code-give-error-1066-not-unique-table-alias-user)

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Next time start with google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's 'cause you are joining on the same table, which needs a table alias in order to avoid confusion, as illustrated below

```
FROM
    categories
INNER JOIN
    categories
```

Change it to below (here c1, c2 are table aliases)

```
FROM
    categories c1
INNER JOIN
    categories c2 
ON
    c1.parent = c2.id
```

and adjust the SELECT clause accordingly