# laravel relation using MySQL join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a relation in my Product Model  and it's working fine

```
        self::where('products.id', '=', $id)
        ->select('products.category_id', 'main_categories.id as main_category_id')
            ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('main_categories', 'categories.main_category_id', '=', 'main_categories.id')
                    ->first();
```

i have replaced it with

```
        self::where('products.id', '=', $id)
        ->select('products.category_id', 'categories.id as parent_id')
            ->join('categories', 'products.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                ->join('categories', 'categories.parent_id', '=', 'categories.id')
                    ->first();
```

Now i get this error

> Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias:
>   'categories' (SQL: select `products`.`category_id`, `categories`.`id`
>   as `parent_id` from `products` inner join `categories` on
>   `products`.`category_id` = `categories`.`id` inner join `categories`
>   on `categories`.`parent_id` = `categories`.`id` where `products`.`id`
>   = 13 limit 1)

Comment: you are joining `categories` table two times. is that you expecting?

Comment: you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435177/why-does-this-sql-code-give-error-1066-not-unique-table-alias-user

Comment: you are joining `categories` table two times. is that you expecting? if yes, please add alias name by simple adding `->join('categories as category1', ........`

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran yes I'm joining categories table two times

Comment: `->join('categories', 'categories.parent_id', '=', 'categories.id')` check this statement...Why you join `categories` with `categories`

Comment: add alias name for your tables and try. please check my previous commnts

Comment: @jitheshjose so i could get categories with children

Comment: @SandeepSudhakaran Can you make it as answer please ?

Comment: `categories` table have a field `parent_id` ?

Comment: @jitheshjose yes

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same table two times for joining without using any alias names.

please refer the below code

```
self::where('products.id', '=', $id)
        ->select('products.category_id', 'cate1.id as parent_id')
            ->join('categories as cate1', 'products.category_id', '=', 'cate1.id')
                ->join('categories as cate2', 'cate1.parent_id', '=', 'cate2.id')
                    ->first();
```

**NOTE:** hope, the `parent_id` you refered from `cate1`. if not please, feel free to change the alias name to appropriate.

Comment: I made some edit. get the latest answer please. it is because I forgot to add alias in select

Comment: coool. happy coding. hope you understood the problem. if not feel free to ask.

Comment: I did Thanks a lot