# alias all column in a query with a prefix

Tags: oracle, select, jdbc, alias

it's possible to alias all column with a prefix, in a select?
I have a group of tables in an Oracle db that I need to join together, and most of them have the same column names. I would like to have something like

```
select MAGIC_ADD_PREFIX("PREFIX", *) from TABLE
```

and have a result like

```
+---------+----------+----------+
|PREFIX_ID|PREFIX_FOO|PREFIX_BAR|
+---------+----------+----------+
|...      |          |          |
```

ATM the only thing I can think is something chumsky like

```
select ID PREFIX_ID, FOO PREFIX_FOO, BAR PREFIX_BAR from TABLE
```

but it's ugly as hell and error-prone

==== further explanation ====

The problem with

```
select TABLE.*,...
```

is that I'm using java + jdbc drivers to retrieve the columns, and the `java.sql.ResultSet` methods (`resultset.getInt("COLUMNNAME")`, `.getString("COLUMNNAME")`...) doesn't support the syntax "TABLENAME.COLUMNAME".

if I do (simplified, no error cheks...)

```
ResultSet rs = mkResultSet("select * from table_a, table_b");
rs.next();
System.out.println(rs.getInt("table_a.id"));
```

I get a `SQLException` with invalid column name as message

Comment: dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329931/sql-select-join-is-it-possible-to-prefix-all-columns-as-prefix

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
select a.*, b.* from table_a a, table_b b where.....
```

Or you could create views over the base tables like

```
   create view a_vw as select a.col1 a_col1, a.col2 a_col2...
```

You could generate the SQL for creating a_vw fairly easily from selecting the column name from user_tab_columns

Comment: In Oracle SQL Developer `select a.* from table_a a;` does not create a Prefix. Also creating a view is as error-prone as adding the alias in the select.