# MySql SELECT AS - Append all field names

Tags: mysql

I'd like to do something like this:

```
SELECT table.id AS prefix_id, table.name AS prefix_name
```

... and have the prefix added dynamically to all field names rather than selecting them all manually (ie `SELECT table.* AS prefix_*` or something)

Hopefully I've described that accurately.  Any thoughts?

**Edit**

To be clear, the reason I'm asking is to make sure that my query result contains *every* column from each table I call even if there are duplicate field names. For example, I might have a table with lots of fields which means I don't want to alias all the fields manually. Further if 3 tables have a field called `name` my result won't contain three `name` results; it will have one. **I want to avoid ambiguity** with my column names.

Comment: What is the purpose of the prefixes? I think I have an idea, but it would depend on the context of your problem.

Comment: If I'm pulling information from two tables and both have an index of 'id' and a column 'name' it won't return results from both tables.

Comment: Edited the question to *hopefully* be more helpful.

Comment: This seems like a very similar question asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329931/sql-select-join-is-it-possible-to-prefix-all-columns-as-prefix Might want to check out that discussion.

Comment: @itsmatt right you are.  Exact same question. With a little more mysql.com research I came across this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html which speaks of ambiguity but not the solution I was hoping for.  If someone wants to answer this I'd rather not delete it.

Comment: I am starting to hate contributors answering :why do you need this or suggesting solution that Jay is obviously trying to avoid... (manualy prefix columns) consider table with lot of columns. Have the same problem, but I would like to avoid prefixes in Where condition at all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid ambiguity in columns with multiple tables it appears you must manually specify each column name that exists with the same name in more than one table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Answer (score -1):

When you reference the results, you can reference each column by the tablename.column .  Therefore you have a default prefix that is appended to each column name.

```
SELECT table.id,table.name,other.name FROM table,other Where other.name = table.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

In mysqli you can use the php function

> mysqli_fetch_fields()

for fieldinformations - so you get the tablename of each collumn