# PHP mysqli prepare statement not working

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am using a mysqli prepare statement to query my db with multiple constraints. I have ran the code in a test file of mine and it works perfectly fine. However, when I move the code over to my live file it throws the error below:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables
>   doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in
>   C:\wamp\www\firecom\firecom.php on line 80
>
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: results in
>   C:\wamp\www\firecom\firecom.php on line 89

Both parameters are being set correctly but something is throwing it off.

Code:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM calls WHERE wcccanumber = ? && county = ?");
$query->bind_param("ss", $wcccanumber, $county);
$query->execute();

$meta = $query->result_metadata();

while ($field = $meta->fetch_field()) {
    $parameters[] = &$row[$field->name];
}

call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

while ($query->fetch()) {
    foreach($row as $key => $val) {
        $x[$key] = $val;
    }
    $results[] = $x;
}

print_r($results['0']);
```

$query var_dump:

```
object(mysqli_stmt)#27 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(-1) ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(2) ["field_count"]=> int(13) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }
```

Comment: can you use && in an sql query? i thought it was AND inside a WHERE clause. try SELECT * FROM calls WHERE wcccanumber = ? AND county = ?

Comment: @JeffHawthorne Actually, `&&` is a synonym to AND in mysql: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and

Comment: The `$results` warning is easy -- The server is checking for undefined variables and your local one isn't. Define `$results` before the `while($query->fetch())` loop and it will go away.

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump variables you are passing to bind_param function? Possibly one of them is empty and is not recognized like a passed value (just a wild guess, but who knows...)

Comment: Yes you can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750648/select-from-in-mysqli

Comment: @FAngel Yes I have and they are correctly set!

Comment: I add the var dump of the query as well.

Comment: Which line is 80 in your example exactly?

Comment: @FAngel call_user_func_array(array($query, 'bind_result'), $parameters);

Comment: It seems that you need single quotes (or backtick ?) around `type` string.  You have double-quotes: "**ss**" `$query->bind_param("ss", $wcccanumber, $county);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why torture yourself with mysqli?
In [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) you will need none of these horrendous codes, but only one line to get the results

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM calls WHERE wcccanumber = ? && county = ?");
$query->execute(array($wcccanumber, $county));
$results = $query->fetchAll();
print_r($results[0]);
```