# Converting to Prepared Statements - How to echo results of the query

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm converting a query to prepared statements for the first time and I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract the data...

Here's my code:

```
/* Create a new mysqli object with database connection parameters */
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_db, $username_db, $password_db, $database_db);
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
  exit();
}

   if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?")) {
      /* Bind parameters, s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
      $stmt -> bind_param("i", $rid);
      $stmt -> execute();
      $stmt -> bind_result($result);
      $stmt -> fetch();
      $stmt -> close();
   }    
   $mysqli -> close();
```

In this example, I was able to display the results in the body of the page like this:

```
<?php echo $results; ?>
```

However, when I changed the query in the example above to grab all the fields, I couldn't figure out how to display it:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?
```

This did not work:

```
<?php echo $results['id'] ?>
```

What am I missing here?  How would I display a random field name from that query?

THanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to think of storing columns one by one like this:

```
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
```

or use code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/966717/216640), which gives you an array of all columns without specyfing each other.

Comment: I know this answer was downvoted, but ultimately, the link he provided was what I was looking for, so I'm marking it as the answer.

Comment: Thanks, however I love people who downvote for no reason or fear to comment and say what's wrong with my answer. Good luck and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Bind a variable per-column in the query:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT foo, bar, baz ...");
$stmt->bind_result($foo, $bar, $baz);
```

Comment: Uhg!  I was afraid it would be something like that.  Here's my issue:  The 'real' query is: select field1, field2, field3, up to maybe field 30 or 40.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it won't work this way as you choose wrong driver, which renders prepared statements quite unusable.

Here is the right code using [the right driver](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info):

```
/* Create a new PDO object with database connection parameters */
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8";
$opt = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
);
$pdo = new PDO($dsn,'root','', $opt);    

/* Prepare a query, bind parameters and execute them */
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stmt -> execute(array($rid));
$row = $stmt -> fetch();
```

Now you can echo result the way you prefer, which is way more useful than one offered by mysqli

```
<?=$row['id'] ?>
```

Note the dramatically shortened code.