# MySQL query prepared statement not returning any result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I am running this query it is not returning any results. **I believe there must be a syntax error** as it is stopping the code from running later down the page. Anyway, I can't see where I am going wrong.

If nothing seems to be the problem with the syntax I can post my database structure, if necessary.

```
    $tag = $_GET['tag'];
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT trips.trip_id FROM tags JOIN trips ON trips.post_id = tags.post_id WHERE tag = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $tag);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($trip_id); ?>

    <div id="map_canvas<?php echo $trip_id ?>" style="height:400px;"></div><?php
```

Update: I have ran the error reporting script and this is what is comes out with...

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /Users/.../server/inc/feed-algorithm.php on line 37
```

Comment: Do you have your error reporting on or off?

Comment: Increase your error_reporting and set display_errors to 1. `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`.

Comment: also close your connection!

Comment: You never called `$stmt->fetch()` to populate `$trip_id`

Comment: @JohnRuddell The connection will be closed implicitly. It is not often necessary to do it manually except as a micro-optimization.

Comment: In your query the parameter is represented by `?` and you're binding it as `s`. How about to change your query to: `'SELECT trips.trip_id FROM tags JOIN trips ON trips.post_id = tags.post_id WHERE tag = :s'`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski its still generally a good practice to close it though

Comment: @Caffé that's a PDO named placeholder. MySQLi only supports `?`. This code is correct, except for the missing `fetch()`.

Comment: @Caffé Then he would have to change `bind_param('s'` to `bindParam(':s'` because this is mysqli and not pdo.

Comment: @Caffé That is PDO syntax/placeholders. `WHERE tag = :s` will not work. OP is using `mysqli_`

Comment: @David If you believe that there is a syntax error, then you're not checking for them.

Comment: Ah, now you updated with the error. Your `prepare()` call didn't succeed, so check `echo $mysqli->error;` to find out why. Always test for success. `if (!$stmt) echo $mysqli->error;`

Comment: Based on your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26197031/ - it seems like it's just that, a "non-object", therefore your query failed. Check your JOIN syntax. You may need a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: <?php  $stmt->bind_result($trip_id); ?> check weather  "trip_id" your binding is available first. Or you may need to move that line ahead of the others and check query was successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php and set up your error statements properly.  Your prepare statement should look like this:

```
if(!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT trips.trip_id FROM tags JOIN trips ON trips.post_id = tags.post_id WHERE tag = ?')){
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Of course, alternatively, throw and handle exceptions if you would like to be a little more elegant and keep your errors from users.

Also follow error checking in the Example 2 section.  It appears your problem is going to be in the prepare statement though because if it was successful, it would not return a 'non-object'.