# How to use logical operators in MYSQLI - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am writig a simple select statement, and since the connection object is mysqli, i cant use AND , && , OR like operators as it giving error

```
function getdata($value1,$value2)
{
global $conn;
$query = "SELECT id, name from users WHERE id!=$value1 && email==$value2 ";
$result = $conn->query($query);
}
```

This dosen't work :-(

Error: trying to get property of non object .. bla bla .. 

 Which means there something wrong with my sql statement, as when i try without logical operators it works, but of no use ofcourse .

**Using prepare statement & bind parameters**
I referred to This thread [SELECT in MYSQLI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750686/1679510)  and tried with prepare statements.. but i'm doing something wrong i guess

```
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT id, name from users WHERE id!=? && email==?");
    $query->bindParam("ss", $value1,$value2); // line 20 error points here
    $query->execute();
```

Error:

```
Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in /mydir/file.php line 20
```

P.S. `var_dump($query);` returns `bool(false)`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html | == is not a valid SQL operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name FROM users WHERE id <> $value1 AND email = '$value2'"
```

`<>` and `!=` is the same. `AND` and `&&` is the same. You probably see `AND` and `<>` because is the standard in SQL. The issue was the equal operator is `=` instead of `==`.

In the second part of your question, `ss` is wrong. `d` is for type double, `s` is for strings.

```
$query=$conn->prepare("SELECT id, name from users WHERE id != ? && email = ?");
$query->bind_param('ds', $value1, $value2);
$query->execute();
```

You can check types on [php bind_param function help](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: Your solution is for without prepare statement right (in my case use case 1) ?
It worked. :-)
I Did not understand having `email = '$value2'` while id<>$value1 did not required the same (the ` mark)
Thanks

Comment: When you compare a numeric field you don't need quotes. Instead if the field is a varchar, you need quotes.

Comment: Ok, but since m using a variable, dosen't it substitute numeric or varchar value in correct format? I know its dumb.. dont mine :D

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems in your query.

> 1. Use ' = ' instead of ' == ' for assignments.
> 2. In the first part You have assigned the query to variable $query, and running the query with variable $sql (wrong)

A modified code will look like this:

```
$query = "SELECT id, name from users WHERE id!='$value1' AND email='$value2'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
```

Comment: Sorry i wrote it wrrong 
2) i do have the correct query in my code.. 
$result = $conn->query($query);

corrected in question.
I'll try wid single "=" and post the result
Thanks

Comment: Yes single "=" worked. That too without prepare statement use case.
Simple Great!! :-)

Answer (score 0):

replace `&&` With `AND`,

replace `==` with "="

its returning `false`, but its because you have a `mysq`l syntax error, you could also try turn on error reporting to see the exception