# First row from MySQL query result not displayed where it should be

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreach

I'm trying to get a SQL query to run through an array showing a list of airline names. However the first result is always empty

1.

2. Cathay Pacific
3. British Airways

Singapore Airlines

etc, when it should show:

1. Cathay Pacific
2. British Airways
3. Singapore Airlines

The code I've got is:

```
foreach ($flights as $b) {
$flightdata = explode(" ", $b);
$airline = $flightdata[2];


$link = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xxx") or die(mysql_error());

$fetchairlinecode = "SELECT * FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  '$airline' LIMIT 0 , 30";

$rs=mysql_query($fetchairlinecode);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

echo $row['airlinename'];   
}

mysql_close($link); 

}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There's probably a row in your database with no airline name? Or there simply isn't a row for the iatacode you have in `$flightdata`?

Comment: have you tried using the sql query directly in your db?
And where do you print the numbers? Or you mean there is an empty row?

Comment: If so, you should try the query in your db, because it could be an arlinename='' someware.

Comment: I don't think it is an empty row, as even if I change the order of the airline names it still moves the first name into the second position. My code displays all the correct results, but they are one position to far along!

Comment: Is there a reason you have mysql_connect inside a foreach loop?

Answer (score 1):

First things first get rid of the non-parametrized query.

```
$fetchairlinecode = 
"SELECT * FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  '$airline' LIMIT 0 , 30";
```

becomes

```
$fetchairlinecode = 
"SELECT airlinename FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  ? LIMIT 30";";
```

and [use mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750686/2224701) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');    
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

foreach ($flights as $b) {
    $flightdata = explode(" ", $b);
    $airline = $flightdata[2];
    $fetchairlinecode = 
    "SELECT airlinename FROM  `airlines` WHERE  `iatacode` =  ? LIMIT 30";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($fetchairlinecode);
    $stmt->bind_param( "s", $airline); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($airlinename);
    while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
        echo $airlinename;
    }
}
$mysqli->close();
```

**Do not use [now long obsolete mysql library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/2224701).**

Open your database connection only once before the foreach statement.

Instead of [`LIMIT 0 , 30`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp) you can write just `LIMIT 30`.