# PDO query does not return data when inserting date as variable

Tags: mysql, date, pdo

Im trying to get a hold of OOP and PDO. Did some tutorials. In the tutorial i got the query method (so thats not mine...)

but im having troubles with a pdo query

I want to select orders from the database matching a date..... de date comes from a datepicker and returns 2012-12-16 for example therefor

```
$dateInputQuery = date("Y-m-d", strtotime(Input::get('datepick')));
$data = $order->getAllOrders('order', 'WHERE DATE(orderdate) = DATE({$dateInputQuery})', false, false);
```

the strange thing is that when i replace the WHERE clause to WHERE DATE(orderdate) = \'2013-12-16\' it returns all the data but when inserting my date like above it does not....

in the db class the method looks like this

```
public function getAll($table, $where = NULL, $orderSort = NULL, $limit = NULL) {
    $this->query("SELECT * FROM {$table} {$where} {$orderSort} {$limit}")->error();
    return $this;
}
```

and query method in db class

```
public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
    //reset error
    $this->_error = false;
    if ($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

        $x = 1;
        if (count($params)) {
            foreach ($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x,$param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if ($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

why is this ?

Comment: Double check that $dateInputQuery is actually in the format you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your immediate problem is caused the fact that `$dateInputQuery` is unquoted. Date is a string literal and should be quoted. And even though you can easily add quotes around it you **really shouldn't do** this. See next point.
2. `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL, therefore the table name should be put in backticks

   ```
   $data = $order->getAllOrders('`order`', "WHERE DATE(orderdate) = DATE('$dateInputQuery')", false, false);
                                 ^     ^                                 ^               ^
   ```
3. You're not leveraging **parameter binding** in `query()` function. Instead on top of it you're using query string interpolation leaving your code vulnerable to sql injections and diminishing the usage of [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements). When you use parameter binding you no longer need to quote parameter values.
4. Your sql query is not index-friendly. You shouldn't apply any functions (in your case `DATE()`) to the column you're searching on (`orderdate`). Instead you can rewrite your condition to apply necessary transformations/calculations to the arguments which are constants.
5. You should avoid using `SELECT *`. Read [Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65512/1920232) and [Why is using '*' to build a view bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/262450/1920232)

That being said your query should look something like

```
$sql = "SELECT order_id, orderdate, ...
          FROM `order` 
         WHERE orderdate >= ? 
           AND orderdate <  ? + INTERVAL 1 DAY";
```

And you should execute it

```
$this->query($sql, array($dateInputQuery, $dateInputQuery));
```

Instead of passing whole clauses (e.g. `WHERE`) you should pass values

Comment: even if I add quotes it wont work (just for checking), thanks for the rest,, ill try it! I only dont understand the 2 times $sql 1 as parameter in array and 1 in query (that one is mine...) but why double ?

Comment: @rZaaaa If you quote it correctly it should work. Also see updated answer. You should put the table name in back ticks because `order` is a reserved word in MySQL. Now you absolutely right there is no need to pass `$sql` second time it was just a typo. Corrected it in the answer.

Comment: I made work of all your notes and its working now. I guess the parameter binding was the (main) problem... I really did put proper quotes around the date var,, but de PDO just would not take it. Only as param.. but its for the better i think,, but THANK YOU!