# Is it okay to SELECT * if desired behavior is for the query to automatically add new columns?

Tags: t-sql

I use a view to surface every column in a wide, denormalized table for reporting users.  The reason I use a view instead of the table directly is that the view has logic to control access by user.

Every time I add a column to the wide, denormalized table I want it to automatically show up in the view.  Many here on Stack Overflow say SELECT * is never okay.  In this case is it okay or should I just take the hit of updating the view every time I add a column to the table?

Comment: First of all NEVER is a very poweful word.  Select * is a cost/benefit thing.  Regarding your view, you should indeed update the view when you make structural changes

Comment: I agree, did not find that one until after I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

For the answer to this question I am much indebted to @User12861.  I found this answer here just after posting my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/263320/5627550

"SQL Server doesn't learn about the "new" column when it is added. Depending on what you want this could be a good thing or a bad thing, but either way it's probably not good to depend on it. So avoiding it just seems like a good idea."