# Is it posssible to use a query to select all coumns except few columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Hi all

I am using Mysql.

and I am looking for, Is it posssible to use a query to select all coumns except few columns?

Comment: Can we do it like "SELECT * EXCEPT(column) from table"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it is not possible, the expression "select all except" has not yet been implemented in any existing database.

Comment: To be more specific on the why: 

- Select * is a slow expression that requires the database to fetch column definition for the entire table
- Select column_list is faster but still requires some computation time
- Select * except column_list would be the most inefficient expression requiring processor time like the other two expression together

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by listing the columns specifically, e.g.

```
select col1, col3, col5, othercol
from tbl
```

*(table contains other columns not listed)*

But if your question is about something like (pseudo)

```
select * - (col2,col4)
from tbl
```

meaning, * = all, less col2 & col4, then it hasn't been implemented in any DB system to date.

Comment: I know this but Can we do it like "SELECT * EXCEPT(column) from table"?

Comment: @OM The long and short answers are both - no