# SELECT all (but one column as null)

Tags: mysql, sql, select

in mysql, is it possible to get all columns and data from a table, but select the ID column as NULL?

Something like

```
SELECT *, id AS (SELECT '') FROM my_table WHERE 1
```

I want to pull in the ID column, so it doesn't mess up the column count for a later data load, but I want to eliminate the column's value so it doesn't cause key conflicts.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I should specify a little more clearly-- the table has probably 80 columns-- I'd much prefer to use the * notation rather than having to specify the whole column list. Thanks

Comment: +1, possible duplicate of [SQL exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) Well, the linked question is more general (not bound to mysql) but the answers are also applicable here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, there is no way to use `SELECT *` and replace one of the columns with another value.

If you don't want to use the select statement provided in your application code, you can create a view with those fields populated and the ID nulled out.  You'll still have to name all the columns at least once.

```
select NULL as ID, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4 from mytable t where col2 = 1
```

Here is the easy way to get all of your column names:

```
SELECT column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = mytable
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT NULL AS ID, Column1, Column2, ..., ColumnN
    FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT *, NULL AS id FROM my_table
```

You'd get `id` listed twice, so you need to expand the `*` to all the column names, for each table you want this to run on.

(If you want column names to be extracted automatically, you can probably use vendor-specific functions; I can't remember if MySQL has any for this situation).

Answer (score 1):

Since it sounds like this is preparatory to a data dump anyway, use a temp table

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t000 AS SELECT * FROM my_table; -- or INSERT INTO
UPDATE t000 SET id = NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. This is not allowed in SQL. You should write all fields and then say null for id.

`SELECT a,b,c,d,e, id as NULL from table`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT null AS id, t.* FROM my_table t
```

But it will include the id twice. You'll need to specify the columns if you only want the null id column.

```
SELECT null As id, t.col1, t.col2 FROM my_table t
```

Answer (score 0):

The truly relational language [Tutorial D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28data_language_specification%29#Tutorial_D) allows a projection (all other other relevant relational operators) to be expressed in terms of the attributes to be removed instead of the ones to be kept e.g.

```
my_relvar { ALL BUT ID }
```

(but being truly relational Tutorial D of course doesn't have a concept of null!)

Sadly, SQL does not have such a language feature and you must write in longhand all the column names.