# I get only those columns name who they are required me with * using MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

I have a table and this table contain 30 columns and I get only those columns name who they are required me with *.

My question is how do I avoid rest of columns name?

For example, result required if possible in MySQL:

```
SELECT *, AVOID('col_13,col_14') FROM `table`
```

**AVOID** is not a function of MySQL I just explain through this.

Why I want this? I required only 20 columns name for a home page and I don't write a query like this because I want optimize or shorter way like `*`.

```
SELECT col_1,col_2,....col_20 FROM `table`
```

This is possible in MySQL.

Comment: Please do not edit out duplicate links if they are automatically added to your posts - this was the reason the question was closed some years back. If you do not believe the question was a duplicate, please cast a reopen vote, or post on Meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query

```
SET @SQL = CONCAT('SELECT ', (SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), 'col_13,col_14,', '') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'table_name' ), ' FROM table_name');

PREPARE stmt1 FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt1;
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's not possible. You need to enumerate **all** required fields

Comment: Which also happens to execute faster...