# select data of specific column from table where column names are returned by query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have written 2 separate queries

1)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_NAME =
       (SELECT DISTINCT UT.TABLE_NAME
          FROM USER_TABLES UT
         WHERE UT.TABLE_NAME = 'MY_TABLE')
   AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('AVOID_COLUMN')
```

2)

```
    SELECT *
      FROM MY_TABLE MT
     WHERE MT.COL1 = '1'
```

The 1st query returns the names of all the columns except the one I want to avoid. The 2nd one returns data of all the columns from the table.
Is there some way to merge these queries so that only those column's data is selected from the 2nd query, which are returned from the 1st query?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my answer to a very similar question asked this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11241724/146325

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use dynamic SQL for this (BTW, I got rid of the subselect for the USER_TABLES query - it's unnecessary):

```
var  cur refcursor
/
declare
  v_stmt varchar2(4000);
begin
  v_stmt := 'SELECT ';  
  for cur in (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME =
       'MY_TABLE'
    AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('AVOID_COLUMN')
  ) 
  loop
    v_stmt := v_stmt || cur.column_name || ',';
  end loop;
  -- get rid of trailing ','
  v_stmt := regexp_replace(v_stmt, ',$', '');

  v_stmt := v_stmt || ' from my_table MT WHERE MT.COL1 = ''1''';
  dbms_output.put_line(v_stmt);
  open :cur for v_stmt;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Frank. However, I was hoping if there was any way to to this in sql completely?

Comment: @Rohan: Sorry, but I have to ask: can't you simply define a view?

Comment: I agree with archimede - a view would be the most simple solution. Apart from that - no, you cannot do it in (static) SQL, since the column list you want to select cannot change; therefore, you have to dynamically create the statement. But why don't you want to use PL/SQL?

Comment: I was trying the query in this way so as to get a query that displays columns EXCEPT a column that I want to avoid. Usually we have to explicitly name the columns we want to display

Comment: Just use a view - create view v_my_view as select <column_list without AVOID_COLUMN> from my_table, and query against that view.