# Inner and left join on the same tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables (A and B) with two columns in common (x and y). I'd like to inner join A and B on x but keep only the values of A's column y (the left join). I'm looking for a way that will combine the two y columns (can't just specify A.y in the select statement). How can I do this?

Example

Table A

```
x  y
1  2
3  4
5  6
7  8
```

Table B

```
x  y
1  2
3  8
9  null
11 0
```

I'd like the resulting table to look like

```
x  y
1  2
3  4
```

Comment: Eh? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Question is unclear, please provide an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.x, a.y
from TableA a
inner join TableB b on a.x = b.x
```

Comment: Edited query based on subsequent info provided.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
INNER JOIN B b1 ON A.x = b1.x
LEFT JOIN B b2 ON a.y = b2.y
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) Second answer. Not the best solution, but you can use this as a workaround. In general, you should specify the full list of columns explicitly.