# SQL - Remove column with same name

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inner and left join on the same tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284502/inner-and-left-join-on-the-same-tables)

I currently have this statement

```
SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A a INNER JOIN B b ON A.x = B.x
```

However, A and B both have a second commonly named column: y. I'd like to only have the y column from A (exclude the one from B), without removing the A.* and B.* parts (many other columns in each table that may or may not always be there). Is this possible?

Example

A

```
x  y  
0  3
1  4
2  5
```

B

```
x  y
0  8
1  null
9  7
```

result

```
x  y
0  3
1  4
```

Comment: You should always use a column list.

Comment: @Andrew, please don't re-post the same question, I've already answered this for you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12284527/39430

Comment: @Andrew why do you want to use `A.*` or `B.*`?  Why not specify the column names?

Comment: as i've said in my answer below (*which was downvoted*), you can't because, asterisk means `ALL`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at 
[SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)
Second answer. Not the best solution, but you can use this as a workaround.
In general, you should specify the full list of columns explicitly.