# SQL Select All and change the format of one column

Tags: sql, select, casting

I was wondering. 
If I have a table with 20(or more) column names in and I want to select All of them, but one column of those 20 columns is a date column and you would like to change the format of that column, how would you do that?
This obviously didn't work (created duplicate columns)

```
Select *, CONVERT(varchar(100),courseStartDate,111) from EthicsManagement
```

This is to avoid writing a select statement selecting ALL 20 columns individually and converting one of them with the statement

```
  Select xxxx,xxx,xxx,xxx,xx,xx,xxx,xxx,xx,xx,xxx,xxx,xx, CONVERT(varchar(100),courseStartDate,111) from xxx
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It should let you do that, as long as you name the column something different:

```
Select *, CONVERT(varchar(100),courseStartDate,111) as myConvertedDateColumn
from EthicsManagement
```

Comment: But still wont it have a duplicate column? a Column with the wrong format and one with the right format. (because we first select *)

Comment: Correct.  And that what sucks about doing a SELECT *

Comment: Well that sucks... So you cant just change that one column format without selecting EACH and every column individually even though you want to select * in that table.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select t.*, CONVERT(varchar(100),courseStartDate,111) as converted from EthicsManagement t
```

Comment: You should add some explanations of what you did different, than OP and why in order to provide a more complete answer.

Answer (score -1):

I see two options:

1. Use the SCRIPT AS TABLE menu option to have it automatically type out all column names and then remove the one you don't want (and add your CONVERT() function there) - [See this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11465635/2479593);
2. Create a TEMP table where you DROP COLUMN the duplicate column - [See this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/2479593).