# How to remove the first column from a temp table select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a temparory table.temp table is created using select into statement.

Temp table columns are dynamically created .column numbers may vary.

```
For eg.
Temparory table
ID,Addrss1,Address2,Address3

ID, Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Address5.....
```

All temp columns have the First column as ID.I need to create a view with base table and
temp table

I need to avoid the first column of the temporary table  in the select statement of the view.I cannot take temp.*.it will take ID.I do not want ID in the select statement.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Refer below link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just try below script:

```
/* Get the data into a temp table */
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM YourTable
/* Drop the cloumns that are not needed */
ALTER TABLE #TempTable
DROP COLUMN ColumnToDrop
/* Get results and drop temp table */
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Comment: If the column is dropped, i cannot join the temp table with  main table

Comment: Use another temp table to temporary store table values.. Otherwise you manually need select only required columns in view