# SQL select query with one or two column excluded

Tags: sql, select, filter, required

how to write a select query with one or two column excluded instead of list down required columns.

for example we have a table Table1 with 10 columns (col_1,col_2,col_2 ..... col_10)
and we just want select col_1 to col_8.

instead of writing like

```
Select col_1, col_2, col_3 .... col_8 from Table1
```

should we select like this

```
Select -(col_9, col_10) * from Table1
```

Comment: No, there is no standard way of doing that.

Comment: since you havent named a dbms, i guess you are asking for sql standard. the answer for that is: not possible

Comment: you cant do that, its always better to mention which columns are required rather than which are not required

Comment: Could you try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6691661/835239 ?

Answer (score 0):

This *is* possible but you would have to use dynamic SQL or a stored procedure. It would still mean having to specify the start and end column using fixed column names and indexes and if the columns weren't in running order (colN, colN+1, etc.) then it would become messy.

So I suppose your answer it, just type it out. The benefit you will gain from doing something cleaver is small.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Any ideas?

I think we can select column name first then write into query.

1 Select column with excluded.

> SHOW COLUMNS FROM _table WHERE FIELD NOT IN ('column1','column2')

2 Then, Use the column result we've got from above query to write to select query column.

> SELECT {result_aboved} FROM _table WHERE 1

but I don't think it can be only once query for this case.   you have to query twice times at least.

Comment: Can you turn to process in store procedures?