# how to select all columns but one in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql, sql-server

is there a way to select all the columns but one specific I don't want to be selected?
I mean sometimes I have that problem that table has hundreds of fields and I need to get rid of one only. Do I need to rewrite all columns? is there a trick to that?
like `select * -<column_name> from table` ?
thanks

Comment: Create a view that has whatever columns you want and select * from view

Comment: NO you need to sepcify columns, Of course you can drag them over from the object browser to dsave key strokes. Of course you shoudl be always specifying columsn in every query as select * should not be usedin production code.

Comment: possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Comment: I do lke Kiran's sugestion though.

Comment: sorry, this question indeed been answered already - so there is no way besides tricks and walk around. thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit long for a comment.

You need to write all the columns or use dynamic SQL.  However, getting all the columns into the query is not necessarily that hard.  You can query the metadata (such as `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`), choosing the appropriate columns for your query.

In SQL Server Management Studio, you can browse to the table.  Under the table name is the "Columns" header.  Then just drag "Columns" into the query pane.  Voila!  All the columns in the table are inserted.  You can manually delete the one you want to delete.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a third party intellisense provider.  Many are free and will add the list of columns for you, then you can just remove the one you don't want.  I use SQL Prompt from Red Gate, which isn't free, but saves me tons of time, and so it's worth the money.