# Drop column in DBVisualizer-query

Tags: sql, db2

I'm looking for a way to drop single columns from an extended query in DBVisualizer. I have a couple of tables with more than one hundred columns each. Using a number of subqueries I want to drop a single column from one of the tables, something like that:

```
select *
from table1 a
join table2 b
on a.key = b.key
drop b.key;
```

I defenitely do not want to write down all the single columns, because the query is supposed to be used for a long time and the tables get new columns to often to change the query each time.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks
Felix

Comment: **(1)** Please add a tag with the relevant database (MySQL / Oracle / SQL Server / PostgreSQL etc.) + version **(2)** Do you mean that you want to delete rows from table2  that have a match in table1?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24557317/330315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/729197/330315

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42518052/330315

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I truly want to delete columns as explained (not coded). I had more tags, no idea where they were lost.

Comment: Still not clear, please add a data sample including required results. I've removed the irrelevant tags. dbvisualizer is a query tool and it is not relevant to your question.

Comment: DBVisualizer is the tool that I am using.  So I guessed it could be relevant.  The column key is a primary key of table b and it is contained in both tables.  In fact the table I get will be joined with a couple of further tables and I want the user to be able to select the columns he needs with the ${...}$-parameter-option in dbvisualizer. However this doesn't work for columns that are in more than one of the tables used.