# SQLServer - Exclude NTEXT columns while comparing data using EXCEPT/INTERSECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ntext

In my SQL, I would need to compare data between two tables in SQLServer 2008R2 to return the rows where mismatch is present (using `EXCEPT`) and likewise matching rows in other cases (`INTERSECT`). The problem is, some of the columns have `NTEXT` datatype (SQLServer), and SQLServer gives error when such tables having columns with `NTEXT` are present.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM table_pre
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM table_post
```

The above operation gives an error -

```
'The ntext data type cannot be selected as DISTINCT because it is not comparable.'
```

I believe that tables (`table_pre`, `table_post`) have at least one column of datatype = `NTEXT` that is causing the comparison to fail.

Question -
1. Is there some way to exclude these `NTEXT` columns from the above comparison, without me having to explicitly list out the column names and excluding the problem column? There's a large number of columns involved and explicitly listing is not easy.
2. Can I just explicitly cast/convert the `NTEXT` column alone to say `VARCHAR`, and still go by not having to list down the rest of the columns?
3. Or, in general, can I somehow exclude certain columns by listing those out during such comparisons?

Any suggestions, really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's easy, you just need to click and drag the "columns" from the table in SMSS.

Comment: 1. No 2. No 3. No - Need to list all columns or hack in the solution found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Answer (score 1):

> Question - 1. Is there some way to exclude these NTEXT columns from the above comparison,

Yes, use explicitly the column names.

> without me having to explicitly list out the column names and excluding the problem column?

Using * is a bad habit, you well deserve the error for abusing it.

> There's a large number of columns involved and explicitly listing is not easy

Is actually trivial, build the statement dinamycally

> Can I just explicitly cast/convert the NTEXT column alone to say VARCHAR

No. You have to convert to NVARCHAR, the N is *very* important. But, yes you can convert.

> 3. Or, in general, can I somehow exclude certain columns by listing those out during such comparisons

Fortunately no. SQL does not randomly decide what columns are or are not part of a result, so you get the predictability you desire.

So, in conclussion:

- never use `*`
- build complex statements dynamically. SELECT ... FROM sys.columns is your friend, you can *easily* build it in a few seconds
- ditch the [deprecated TEXT, NTEXT and IMAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) types

Comment: Thanks Remus. Let me look at the programmatic way then!