# Replacing old column data with new from left join

Tags: mysql, sql

how can I replace column 'price' from 'products' to new 'price' from 'product_variations' and order by this new 'price'. Thank you for yours answers.

```
SELECT products.*, product_variations.price as `price`
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_variations ON product_variations.product = products.id
ORDER BY price
```

Comment: You can use temp table like in this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Comment: unclear and maybe possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea

Answer (score 0):

`products.*` means `all field`s of `products`. if you don't want `products.price`, so don't use `products.*`, instead of it write all fields of products except than `price`:

```
SELECT 
    products.id,products.field_name_2,
    --...write all fields you want except than price 
    products.field_name_n,
    product_variations.price as `price`
FROM products
LEFT JOIN product_variations ON product_variations.product = products.id
ORDER BY price
```

Comment: `products.*` means `all field`s of `products` so if you don't want all of then you should not use it

Comment: But I need all of them. (my example code is reduced I need more than price)

Comment: you don't know what do you want, if you need them all so whay you told: _how can I replace column 'price' from 'products' to new 'price' from 'product_variations'_ !!???? :(

Comment: you are bothering others here. if _order is not just by price_ so why you have `ORDER BY price`(only price) in your code. I hope your question will get closed.

Comment: This is irrelevant. I want just replace one column with data from other.