# How to exclude one column from result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...,z
```

Is it possible to write a simple query that will gives all columns except `a` without manualy specifing all other columns?

something that will be equivelant to:

```
Select b,c,d,e,f,g,h,...z
from TableG
```

Comment: You mean like `SELECT b to z FROM xxxx` ? I don't think so !

Comment: yes, thats what I mean.

Comment: I think you have to explicitly mention the subset of columns to be returned

Comment: That much I know... but the table has 43 columns and I need 42 of them. I guess I'll write a query that will give me the table column names it would be easier.

Comment: @SMW Create a view like `create view vTableg selct b,..,..z from tableg` and whenever you need that columns then simply call `select * from vTableg `

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question, you cannot do that directly, **HOWEVER** i found a solution for you.

The `SELECT` statement of SQL when using **Physical table** can only do `SELECT *` that will return all columns and `SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3...` for specific columns, there is no `WHERE` condition that will exclude 1 column name in the `SELECT` statement of SQL. How ever you can manipulate the table and the data the way you wanted it using **temporary table**

**Solution:**

1. Insert into temp table
2. Drop the column that you want to exclude from the temp table
3. Select all data from temp table.

   ```
   SELECT * INTO #TempTable
   FROM TableG

   ALTER TABLE #TempTable
   DROP COLUMN a

   SELECT * FROM #TempTable

   DROP TABLE #TempTable
   ```

I found the solution here: [SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Comment: Interesting indeed but performance could by bottleneck for big tables. So I recommend to think twice before applaying this solution in production environment. Nonetheless nice for simple-every-day-debbug work.

Answer (score 1):

```
/************************************************************
Function To Split Strings
************************************************************/

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.SplitString') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
END
GO

create function [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @String varchar(max),
    @Delimiter char(1)
)
returns @SplittedValues table
(
    str_item varchar(100) primary key
)
as
begin
    declare @SplitLength int

    while len(@String) > 0
    begin 
        select @SplitLength = (case charindex(@Delimiter,@String) when 0 then
            len(@String) else charindex(@Delimiter,@String) -1 end)

        insert into @SplittedValues
        select substring(@String,1,@SplitLength) 

        select @String = (case (len(@String) - @SplitLength) when 0 then  ''
            else right(@String, len(@String) - @SplitLength - 1) end)
    end 
return  
end
GO


/************************************************************
Function To Get columns names excluding some of them
************************************************************/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.get_columns') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.get_columns
END
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_columns 
(
   @table_name varchar(100),
   @excluded_column_names varchar(100),
   @delimter char(1)
)
RETURNS varchar(4000)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @cols varchar(4000)
    select @cols = COALESCE(@cols+',' ,'') + name
    from sys.columns 
    where object_id=object_id(@table_name) 
        and name not in (select str_item from dbo.SplitString(@excluded_column_names,@delimter))
    return @cols
END
GO


/************************************************************
Function To Get columns names excluding some of them
************************************************************/
declare @qry nvarchar(max)
set @qry = ' select ' + dbo.get_columns('TableName','Exclude_col_1,Exclude_col_2,Exclude_col_3',',') 
    + ' from TableName'
    + ' where condition'
EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry
GO
```

Comment: There are two functions 1.) SplitString 2.) get_columns. At last I have shown how can we use get_columns in a dynamic query to exclude columns.