# BigQuery select * except two columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to select everything from the public BigQuery github_repos dataset except from two records: author.name **AND** difference.old_mode. Based on a similar question I asked, I think I want to run a query similar to

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT author.* EXCEPT (name)) AS author), 
REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT difference.* EXCEPT (old_mode)) AS difference)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 1000;
```

If I run the author exclusion, it works well:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT author.* EXCEPT (name)) AS author)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 1000;
```

However, the difference exclusion has an error:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE ((SELECT AS STRUCT difference.* EXCEPT (old_mode)) AS difference)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 1000;
```

Error:

```
Dot-star is not supported for type ARRAY<STRUCT<old_mode INT64, new_mode INT64, old_path STRING, ...>> at [2:41]
```

Thank you.

**Update**
Not a duplicate of [SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Comment: Thank you, but that MS SQL server link doesn't really help me here unfortunately.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As a self-contained example, consider this query:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 10 AS a, ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>[
      (1, 'foo', true)] AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>[
      (2, 'bar', false), (3, 'baz', true)]
)
SELECT * FROM T;
```

It returns a column `a` of type `INT64` and a column `arr` of type `ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>`. If you wanted to return a modification of `arr` where the struct inside the array omits `y`, you could use a combination of `SELECT * REPLACE` and `SELECT * EXCEPT`:

```
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 10 AS a, ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>[
      (1, 'foo', true)] AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>[
      (2, 'bar', false), (3, 'baz', true)]
)
SELECT * REPLACE(ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (y) FROM UNNEST(arr)) AS arr)
FROM T;
```

The idea is to replace the original array with a new one, and we use an `ARRAY` subquery with `SELECT AS STRUCT` and `* EXCEPT` to reconstruct the array with struct elements whose fields don't include `y`.

Going back to the query in the question, you can apply the same idea to `difference` and `old_mode`:

```
SELECT * REPLACE (
  ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT * EXCEPT (old_mode) FROM UNNEST(difference)) AS difference
)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT 1000;
```

The query result contains a `difference` array whose struct doesn't include the `old_mode` field.

Comment: You're awesome; thank you so much. For anyone referencing this in the future, to complete the example with my question, all that needs to be done is the other replace query line I had working added to the replace function Elliott had above. This successfully removes both fields.

Comment: @Elliott  What if my table structure is the one below. How should I change my query. WITH T AS (
  SELECT 10 AS a, STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>
      (1, 'foo', true) AS arr UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>
      (2, 'bar', false)
)

Comment: Please submit a new question.