# SQLITE SELECT * EXCEPT SOME COLUMNS

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLITE Database with a Table. In this table, I have 137 columns, and I want to select all the content except some columns. I saw the "Temp table" method, but I was wondering if there is another way to solve this problem.

Comment: 137 columns does not sound like a good schema.

Comment: ISO-ALPHA 2 country codes and some optional columns. I need to save from where a request on a specific page is coming. I think there isn't any other way to do that.

Comment: This is not a good schema; the value(s) for each country code should go into a separate row.

Comment: The `EXCEPT` is for rows, not for columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)