# alaising a foreign key in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have two tables `contacts` and `departments`.

The contents of the table are as follows:

contacts:

```
id |  first_name | last_name | email            | department_id
10 |  Mani       | Raj       | raj@mail.com     | 2
11 |  Santhos    | Sam       | santhos@mail.com | 3
```

departments:

```
id | department_name
1  | HR
2  | Sales
3  | Finance
```

I'm trying to print the details of the tables using `INNER JOIN`

My query is:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM contacts INNER JOIN departments, departments.id as departments.department_id ON contacts.department_id=departments.department_id ORDE`R BY contacts.id";
```

I've referred the question below:
[SQL exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

but I don't want to create a temporary table.

I was thinking may be there was a way for alaising the id column from the department table.

**Add**

I could print the elements from the tables using the query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT * FROM $table_name INNER JOIN departments ON $table_name.department_id=departments.department_id ORDER BY $table_name.id";
```

It works great but the problem is when I try to print the details on my web page, somehow the `id` from the `contacts` table is overwitten by the `id` from the `departments` table.

code that I use to print the table is:

```
if ($query_result->num_rows > 0) {
            ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th> First Name </th>
                    <th> Last Name </th>
                    <th>E-mail</th>
                    <th>Department</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                while($row = $query_result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["id"]; ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["first_name"]; ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["last_name"]; ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["email"]; ?> </td>
                        <td> <?php echo $row["department_name"]; ?> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
            <?php           
        }
```

The output of this code is :

```
ID | First Name | Last Name     | E-mail            | Department
2  | Mani       | Raj           | mani@mail.com     | Sales
8  | Santhos    | Sam           | santhos@mail.com  | Finance
```

whereas my output should be:

```
ID | First Name | Last Name     | E-mail            | Department
10 | Mani       | Raj           | mani@mail.com     | Sales
11 | Santhos    | Sam           | santhos@mail.com  | Finance
```

Now how would I go about printing the values without being overwritten?

I'm a newbie. Please help me...

**Edit**

OK,cool this works

```
$sql_query = "SELECT *, contacts.id as id FROM contacts INNER JOIN departments 
ON contacts.department_id=departments.department_id ORDER BY contacts.id";
```

But I'm also trying to export the details to a .xls file.
I'm getting an error there!!

This is my error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax     check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'as id FROM  INNER JOIN departments ON .department_id=departments.id ORDER BY .id' at line 1<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/opt/lampp/htdocs/contacts/export.php</b> on line <b>23</b><br />
```

and my code is:

```
$flag = false;
foreach($query_result as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
        // display field/column names as first row
        echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\r\n";
        $flag = true;
    }
    array_walk($row, __NAMESPACE__ . '\cleanData');
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\r\n";
}

function cleanData(&$str) {
        $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
        $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
        if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell SQL from which table you want the data:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT t1.id, t1.first_name, t1.last_name, t1.email, t2.department_name 
FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN departments t2 ON t12.department_id=t1.id 
ORDER BY t1.id";
```

When you have same field in both tables (like ID in your case), SQL is confused which one to pick.

It's not good practice to use * as it might break your application once your table structure changes, however, if you must use it, following will work:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.department_name 
FROM contacts t1
INNER JOIN departments t2 ON t2.department_id=t1.id 
ORDER BY t1.id";
```

And here is the example with "dynamic" tables

```
$sql_query = "SELECT t1.*, t2.department_name 
FROM $table_name t1
INNER JOIN departments t2 ON t2.department_id=t1.id 
ORDER BY t1.id";
```

To make this fully dynamic, you might do something like following.

I'll use your two tables as a example (not tested but it should put you on the right track):

```
$table1_name = "contacts;
$table1_key = "id";
$table1_fields = "*";

$table2_name = "departments";
$table2_key = "id";
$table2_fields ="department_name";


$sql_query = "SELECT t1.$table1_fields, t2.$table2_fields
  FROM $table1_name t1
  INNER JOIN $table2_name t2 
    ON t2.$table2_key = t1.$table1_key
  ORDER BY t1.$table1_key";
```

Comment: I don't want to name each column

Comment: You are not naming it, you are just telling SQL which one to use. It is never good practice to use * as the structure changes, your app might brake.

Comment: I dont want to specify it!!

Comment: It might be OK for a small application, but when the application gets complex, it will not be efficient

Comment: We have databases that are over 400 GB with over 2000 tables, it doesn't matter, it is still the best practice. You can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful

Comment: Cool... OK now what if I have the table name as dynamic? I must be able to use this code for any two tables!! How could I do than if I specify the fields...??  Could you please explain ..?

Comment: And also how do I clear the error when I export my datas

Comment: It's a typo, I meant "any". Also, I added third example with dynamic table name. Are you confused with my use of t1 and t2? Those are just aliasing.

Comment: I did try your solutions with little alterations... I gives me the expected result.... But I want to make my query so that it can be executed even when the tables are dynamic....!!!!

Comment: Try my third example. Those are really SQL basics.

Comment: I also want the departments table to be dynamic

Comment: It wasn't dynamic in your original question either. Anyhow, how difficult is for you to make it dynamic using my third example? We are here to help you, not really to code for you.

Comment: I understand..... Also I get errors when i export ... What about that...?

Comment: Do you get errors when you execute my third example?

Comment: Looking at the error you are getting on the export, it looks like you are not passing your dynamic table name.

Comment: I'm cool now... But still... I don't really understand... When I make the dapertments table dynamic.. the other table may or may not have department_name column.... I'm just saying that ... What if it doesn't have that column..... Then i will be in trouble right?

Comment: There is no ONE QUERY DOES IT ALL in programming. You create new query for different needs. Solution will also be to pass table filed (department_name in your case) dynamically as well.

Comment: also table names are interchanged after ON in your third answer

Comment: Made correction to answer and also provided you with an idea how to make the hole thing dynamic. Error you are getting is because you are probably not passing $table_name variable into the export.php.

Comment: cool.. now if i have n number of fields in the second table i can store it in an array and use it... Correct..!??? :)

Comment: Kind of, some change would need to be made but this should put you on the right "thinking" direction.

Comment: Great... Thanks a lot.... Now I have an idea on working with dynamic table names!! :) :) :)

Answer (score -1):

Please try this query

```
$sql_query = "SELECT *, contacts.id as id FROM contacts INNER JOIN departments 
ON contacts.department_id=departments.department_id ORDER BY contacts.id";
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two solutions to this and a third possible one.
1)

```
SELECT *, `department`.`id` as `depid`, `contacts`.`id` as `contactid`
```

Then, in your code simply ignore the spurious 'id' column and refer to whichever specific one you want

2) If you are using PHP (it looks like it) and using PDO to access the data, use

```
$stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_NAMED)
```

and you will get both ids in an array instead of one overwriting the other.

You MIGHT get the result you want by flipping around the table references
i.e. instead of

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts INNER JOIN Departments
```

use

```
SELECT * FROM Departments INNER JOIN Contacts
```