# Join On - returns both columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've made a join statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table1 a
JOIN dbo.table2 b ON a.[columnX] = b.[columnY]
```

In the result I have both columns, columnX from table1 and columnY from table2.  Tried to rename the columns to have the same name, but the same has happened. This is quite strange for me coming from Oracle, as a join statement should actually join the tables ON that specific column, shouldn't it?

How do I write the join to leave me only one column from the two?

EDIT: YES, I know * returns all columns. If that wasn't so obvious that is what I want. That is why I've used *, surprise surprise. The question was about how to leave one of the duplicates behind. You may keep reapating that * will return everything a 1000 times, makes no help without a proper answer or suggestions.

Comment: Maybe you want this: select table1.columnX from dbo.table1 JOIN dbo.table2
ON (dbo.table1.[columnX] = dbo.table2.[columnY])

Comment: not sure what your question is, but instead of `select * from` you should select only the columns you want to be in the result and you can give them any name you want.

Comment: @isaaceI 
have a lot of columns, so I can't enumerate them manually. I just want to join the two tables on the common values while getting the rest of the columns from the table too.

Comment: to be honest, I don't understand your question. what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @MattSom If you want all columns from the two tables, the query you provided is correct. If the SELECT * is only returning two columns, it is because your tables each only contain 1 column.

Comment: again, `select * from` will return all columns from all tables, `including the columns used to join 2 tables`. if you want anything else, you will need to be more specific in your `select`.

Comment: I don't know why you guys downvote for any reason. It is clear that I want to keep all columns after the join, just without any duplication on the column it was joined on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the fields that you wish to return. a SELECT * will give you all fields from both tables (including both listed in the JOIN).
use below logic for each field and exclude any you don't want returned.

I've also given aliases to your tables to make the column names easier to follow.

```
    SELECT
     t1.[columnA]
    ,t1.[columnB]
    ,t1.[columnC]
    .
    .
    .
    ,t2.[columnA]
    ,t2.[columnB]
    ,t2.[columnC]
    FROM dbo.table1 t1
    INNER JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.[columnX] = t2.[columnY]
```

An alternative if you really don't want to list all columns would be to SELECT * INTO a temp table, drop the unwanted column(s) from the temp table and then SELECT * from the temp table, found this here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/sql-exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea) and I will add the generic script below in case the link ever dies along with a specific one to match your table with a join.

Although this will work, I would suggest only ever using SELECT * for quick on the fly checks, if this is part of a procedure or a view or something that other processes use, SELECT * could cause knock-on issues/failures if the source table(s) structure changes and the subsequent steps in the process aren't expecting the new change. e.g. a field is dropped from source, view no longer picks it up as part of a SELECT * and procedure will fail as it is expecting it as part of on INSERT task.

Rule of Thumb for myself is to always specific what columns i want in any query other than on the fly data checks.

Generic version for syntax;

```
    /* Get the data into a temp table */
    SELECT * INTO #TempTable
    FROM YourTable
    /* Drop the columns that are not needed */
    ALTER TABLE #TempTable
    DROP COLUMN ColumnToDrop
    /* Get results and drop temp table */
    SELECT * FROM #TempTable
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

Custom version to suit your needs with the joined tables;

```
    /* Get the data into a temp table */
    SELECT * INTO #TempTable
    FROM [dbo].[table1] a
    JOIN [dbo].[table2] b ON a.[columnX] = b.[columnY]
    /* Drop the columns that are not needed */
    ALTER TABLE #TempTable
    DROP COLUMN [columnX]
    /* Get results and drop temp table */
    SELECT * FROM #TempTable
    DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

I found a more elegant way on the same link as above which you can SELECT * dynamically with the below (again I am not condoning SELECT *);

```
    declare @cols varchar(max), @query varchar(max);
    SELECT  @cols = STUFF
        (
            ( 
                SELECT DISTINCT '], [' + name
                FROM sys.columns
                where object_id = (
                    select top 1 object_id from sys.objects
                    where name = 'MyTable'
                )
                and name not in ('ColumnIDontWant1', 'ColumnIDontWant2')
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 2, ''
        ) + ']';

    SELECT @query = 'select ' + @cols + ' from MyTable';  
    EXEC (@query);
```

Comment: But what if both t1 and t2 consists of countless of columns? Do I really have to list them manually?

Comment: you could SELECT * into a temp table, drop the one(s) you don't want from the temp table and then select all from the temp table, I'll edit my answer to include where I found and what it was (as links can die)

Answer (score 1):

Your `SELECT *` means return all columns from all tables referenced in the `FROM` and `JOIN` tables.

It is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1.columnX = table2.columnY
```

So just change the `SELECT` to your explicit columns:

```
SELECT table1.columnX
FROM table1 
JOIN table2
ON table1.columnX = table2.columnY
```

Comment: But I need all the other columns. Selecting just columnX gives me nothing, but that one column.

Comment: If you leave your SELECT as SELECT *, you will return all columns from the tables in your FROM and JOIN. If you want all columns, the query in your original post is correct. To be as specific as possible, put the table structure of both tables in your post and also the expected output.

Comment: I have countless of attributes in both tables, so there is no sense to output that in the question. I want to have all columns, the columns from a and from b, joined by the selected column.

Comment: @MattSom There really isn't another way to say it. I have said it in my comments, people have said it in comments on your original post. If you have SELECT *, all columns from table1 and table2 will be in your output. I don't get what you don't understand. If you want all columns EXCEPT for a certain column, then you have to explicitly list them all out.

Comment: I understand it, that is what I need. Also I've said I only don't want the duplicated columns which I've joined the tables on. The question is how to do it. Instead of helping with that I'm keep reading about * gets everything, like I would have not know that. You may keep downvoting, but that makes zero help and is just plainly a childish move. Just don't contribute instead, no problem comes from that.

Comment: @MattSom If you want all columns, you will get both columns you joined on. If you want only 1 of those, either from table1 or table2, you will have to do SELECT t1.*, t2.col1, t2.col2.....t2.colN. SQL Server doesn't have a way to say SELECT <every column except a certain one>

Comment: @dfundanko Thank you! That was a proper answer I was looking for! I simply don't get it why was that so hard to understand instead of downvoting me. People always start saying to put out all of your columns to be more specific, like people could not have 300 columns in a table to work with.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
select  a.* 
from    dbo.table1 a
JOIN    dbo.table2 b
        ON a.[columnX] = b.[columnY]
```

This statement will return all columns in table1 where the join condition is true i.e. all records in table1 where columnx = columny.