# Is there anyway to do SELECT * EXCEPT (col1, col2, ...) ... in RedShift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In BigQuery I can write:

```
SELECT * EXCEPT (col1, col2, ...) ...
```

Is there an equivalent for RedShift? I don't think there is, but I wanted to see if anyone had any bright ideas.

Incidentally, I find this to be very useful in BigQuery when writing multiple subqueries, each flowing into the next. I can include/exclude columns at the relevant part of the query without having it break something later on, which is very useful when developing a complex query.

Comment: No, that is not supported. See: [SELECT - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SELECT_synopsis.html)

Comment: What do you think this is, bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to my knowledge.

The only `EXCEPT` is the normal `SELECT` functionality to subtract one relation from another.

Comment: Thanks Max - pls also see John Rotenstein's comment on the question, he's confirmed this to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

This answer on a related question might work in Redshift too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/12170 (copy the date to a temporary table, alter that copy by dropping the columns you don't want from it, then use that as input)