# How to exclude some attribute from fetch xml but Retrieve all other attributes

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I want to retrieve all attributes of entity but exclude some of them.
Like if entity have 42 attributes I want to exclude  Name, Date and retrieve all others. Below is what i have tried.

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" >
    <entity name="account" >
        <all-attributes/>
        !<attribute name="name" />!
        <order attribute="statecode" descending="false" />
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
            <condition attribute="location" operator="eq"  uitype="location" value="{11c43ee8-b9d3-4e51-b73f-bd9dda66e29c}" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Referring this SO post - https://stackoverflow.com/q/729197/7920473 -

Very common requirement but not a native functionality in SQL itself.. :) so I would not expect in fetchxml :)

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `<all-attributes/>` node and add all the attributes you want into the fetchXML.
The fetchXml should look like:

```
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false" >
    <entity name="account" >        
        <attribute name="a"/>
        <attribute name="b"/>
        <attribute name="c"/>
        <attribute name="d"/>
        <order attribute="statecode" descending="false" />
        <filter type="and" >
            <condition attribute="statecode" operator="eq" value="0" />
            <condition attribute="location" operator="eq"  uitype="location" value="{11c43ee8-b9d3-4e51-b73f-bd9dda66e29c}" />
        </filter>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Here are some ways to generate a fetchXml:

1. Download from `Advance find`. You can download the fetchXml after you added the columns and conditions you want.[image]
2. Use the [FetchXML Builder](https://fetchxmlbuilder.com/?utm_source=FetchXMLBuilder&utm_medium=XrmToolBox).
3. Use [Dataverse REST Builder](https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB)