# How to exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] in Sybase

Tags: sybase, sap-iq

I want to select all columns but remove some columns in Sybase. What is the solution for this?

I want something like this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
except [column_names]
```

There is no function available for Sybase for this use case and the 'exclude' keyword like snowflake does not work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude a column using SELECT \* \[except columnA\] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

Answer (score 0):

The question is basically a duplicate of this one: [Exclude a column using SELECT * [except columnA] FROM tableA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729197/exclude-a-column-using-select-except-columna-from-tablea)

There are possible workarounds that work with standard SQL, [like using this temp table approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1712243/22338334) (if the performance hit is acceptable)

Because [Sybase has some  "non-standard SQL features"](https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1601/doc/html/san1278453230633.html), but as you mentioned not the EXCLUDE keyword (or a similar feature) which is a [non-standard Snowflake extension](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/6-37-Release-Notes-November-10-11-2022).