# Have table-valued function in T-SQL return table with variable number of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, clr, sqlclr

Is it possible to have a table-valued function in T-SQL return a table with a variable number of columns?
The column names may simply be `1, 2, …, n`.

Right now I have a "string split" function that returns a single-columned `1 x n` table, and I pivot the table afterwards to an `n x 1` table, but I'd rather streamline the process by returning the correct table format to begin with.

I intend to use a CLR procedure in C# for this function, I just don't know how to set up the user-defined function to return my data in the format I want: with a variable number of columns, dependent on the input string.

Comment: The feature is called **[Polymorphic Table Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015504/5070879)** (defined in SQL Standard 2016) - not supported by T-SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to return a non-static Result Set from a Table-Valued Function (TVF), whether it be written in T-SQL or .NET / SQLCLR. Only Stored Procedures can dynamically create a Result Set.

Basically, any function needs to return a consistent result type, whether it is a scalar value or a collection (i.e. Result Set).

However, in a SQLCLR stored procedure, you can create a dynamic Result Set via [SqlMetaData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqlmetadata.aspx). As long as you don't have an explicit need to `SELECT ... FROM` it, then maybe a stored procedure would work.

Of course, you might also be able to get away with doing this in T-SQL, using dynamic SQL to construct a SELECT statement based on the output of your split function.

A lot of this comes down to the exact context in which this functionality needs to be used.

Comment: I know about using SqlMetaData to create a result set in a CLR stored procedure, but is this also possible for a user-defined function?

Comment: No, SqlMetaData is only for Stored Procedures. As mentioned in my answer, a function, regardless of the language, must return a consistent/predefined type. For a CLR function you define a struct to pass the data back in as well as the table definition in the function decorator. There is no way to make either of those places dynamic. I would LOVE it if you could make a function Result Set dynamic, but that just isn't going to happen.