# How to exclude a columns in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have 57 columns in a table , need to display only 53 ,

how can i write query to eliminate other 4 columns

note : i don't want to use " select col1,col2,col3...... from table;"

I need a simple query to exclude those 4 columns

Comment: please... use the forc..err search

Comment: Depending on the tools that you use to query the database, you might be able to auto-generate the select script with all of the columns and then manually remove the 4 that you do not want.  Otherwise I think you might be left with generating dynamic sql, which seems like overkill in this case.

Comment: The simple query is to type select and then choose the columns you want. It's really not that difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you SELECT everything, but 1 or 2 fields, without writer's cramp?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133120/can-you-select-everything-but-1-or-2-fields-without-writers-cramp)

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do this syntactically.  However, lazy programmers (which is a good thing) can find ways to avoid excessive typing.  For instance:

1. SQL*Plus `describe` commnad
2. Cut'n'paste
3. Editor with regex search / replace