# how to find a record from a table with existing record in oracle?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, row

here's a table with a high number of columns

```
create table test (
id    number,
col_1 varchar2(50),
col_2 varchar2(50),
.
.
col_n varchar2(50)
);
```

and the table is filled with some example data

```
insert into test values(1,'a1','a2',...,'an');
insert into test values(2,'a1','a3',...,'am');
insert into test values(3,'a4','a2',...,'ax');
```

now i need to copy one row (fore example the row with id=1) and change just one column's value, if the result does not be similar to another row (without considering id).
some thing like this:

```
declare
 r test%rowtype;
 var1 number;
begin
 insert into r from test where id = 1;
 r.col_2='a3';
 select count (*) into var1 from test where 'the row without id' = r;
 if (var1 = 0) then
  insert into test values r;
 end if;
end;
```

but i don't know how to write the select part in oracle.  consider table test has lots of columns so you can't write all of the columns in where clause.

Comment: Oracle doesn't really limit the number of columns that can be referenced in a `where` clause and it does limit the number of columns in a table.  If there are just a lot of columns, use a meta data table to extract them and generate the code.

Comment: [Related question, perhaps, but not quite the same](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9133120/266304). Maybe also worth considering the possibility of a race condition between when you do the count and when you do the insert; a small window, but two sessions could still clash and insert duplicates. A unique index over all the columns might be a comsiderable overhead but could be considered, maybe, and would speed up the count too.

Comment: Perhaps `where id is null` in your `select` query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is sort of hard to understand what you need.   I'll take a shot here.  Let me know if this is on track....

To make things easy, can you create a unique index on the table?

```
    create unique index test_uidx on test (col_1, col_2, ... col_n);
```

And then let oracle do the work:

```
    declare
      r     test%rowtype;
      var1  number;
    begin
      select * into r from test where id=1;  --- get the row
      r.col_1  := 'some new value';          --- change 1 value

      begin
         insert into test values r;          --- insert the row
      exception
        when dup_val_on_index then           --- row was a dup
          null;                              --- and did not insert
      end;
   end;
```

Comment: i think i can create an index. how does it work? does it insert the row first and if the inserted row was duplicated, oracle will delete that row? can you explain more?

Comment: when a row was duplicate then it would not be inserted and an exception will happen

Comment: When the exception is thrown, control goes into the exception handler,  the record is not inserted and the "null;" line reached and then processing continues.   If the "null;" was changed to "raise;" then a dup_val_on_index error is raised.   By just doing "null;" the error is suppressed.  Make sense?