# Change only single column values when we use * in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to change only single column values as updated in selection of oracle sql.

```
SELECT  ORDD.id||'sdaf' as id,ORDD.* 
FROM RDT_ORDER ORDM,RDT_ORDERDETAIL ORDD;
```

Here in RDT_ORDERDETAIL am having around Hundered columns but only single coulmn I need as updated.

I don't want to select all Hundred columns by writing all columns in select query as below

```
SELECT  ORDD.id||'sdaf' as id,ORDD.col1,ORDD.col2,ORDD.col3,ORDD.col4 
FROM RDT_ORDER ORDM,RDT_ORDERDETAIL ORDD;
```

Please note I have removed where clause,I need to get single updated column values other columns as it is.But I shouldn't write all coulmns in Select.

**Existing DB Records :**

```
ID NAME COL3 COL4
1  name1 ..   ..
2  name2 ..   ..
3  name3 ..   ..
```

**Now Result :**

```
ID       ID NAME COL3 COL4
1_'sdaf' 1  name1 ..   ..
2_'sdaf' 2  name2 ..   ..
3_'sdaf' 3  name3 ..   ..
```

**Expected Result :**

```
ID        NAME COL3 COL4
1_'sdaf'  name1 ..   ..
2_'sdaf'  name2 ..   ..
3_'sdaf'  name3 ..   ..
```

Comment: `single column values as updated in selection of oracle` by this you mean, you want to select only the columns that you updated in your UPDATE query previously?

Comment: What exactly you need to find? What is the point in your join (cartesian!!)? Why dont you have ORDD.COLNAME? Provide some examples and explain clearly

Comment: Please check the udpated Question.Am not updating anything.this is not related to updation.

Comment: Hi Thanks for all your answers

Comment: Why do want to view them this way?  Why not update the table in the DB?  Generally speaking, using `SELECT *` is frowned upon anyways.  I'm also a bit concerned over the fact that your table has 100 (or more) columns - most dbs don't need anywhere near that many in a single table (especially for something that appears to be a transactional database).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select all but one rows then the answer is **No** - [you either get all fields (*) OR specify the fields you want.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm) This is how Oracle works.

If you still persists, then there might be some work around like [Dynamic SQL using query generator or data cartridge](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422)

You can refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133120/can-you-select-everything-but-1-or-2-fields-without-writers-cramp) for similar question.

If you want to have a string manipulation and all columns you can do using alias.

```
SELECT COL1||'_asd_', T.*
FROM MYTABLE T;
```

Your idea of getting all columns from a table with a manipulation on one or more columns without writers cramp is not possible directly. You may try dynamic SQL but I will not suggest that for anything because of low maintainability and its a head ache on a long run.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can exclude a single column by quering with `select * from...`. May be a `VIEW` can help you on this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW <view_name> AS
     SELECT  ordd.id||'sdaf' AS id, ordd.col1, ordd.col2, ordd.col3, ordd.col4 
     FROM    rdt_order ordm,
             rdt_orderdetail ordd
     WHERE   .....;
```

Comment: I would give a +1 for suggesting another alternative. Since you have posted a minute before mine, I removed this content. I do not suggest views unless it is not used frequently. Unfortunately reached the limit for voting today :(