# How to eliminate a column from a pivot'd Oracle table?

Tags: oracle, select, pivot

Platform: Oracle 11g

I have a pivot table which has the "dynamic columns" (*where the actual name of the columns are depending what values are available in the original table as rows*).  This pivot table has a foreign key column that reference to another table.

I'd like the join'd query result to NOT show the foreign key column.  Is there a way I can do that?

NOTE: I can't spell out every column I need, because I don't know what they are or what they will be.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample data, table structure and expected outcome would be useful to provide the precise answer.

Comment: The number and name of the columns for a query has to be known at compile time.  If the number and name of the columns is dynamic, that implies that you are dynamically building the query in which case you'd update the code that dynamically builds the query to dynamically choose which columns to return.  If you are not dynamically building the query, that implies that the number and name of the columns is known in advance and you can simply list the columns you want.

Comment: The answer to my question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133120/can-you-select-everything-but-1-or-2-fields-without-writers-cramp/33220953#comment105993489_33220953)