# Returning value from other table in place of foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have 3 tables.

`table_1`

| id | fk_table_2 | fk_table_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

`table_2`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "foo" |

`table_3`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "bar" |

I'd like to query a row in `table_1` but instead of returning the `fk_table_2` & `fk_table_3`, is there a way to return the `name` associated the the row in their respective tables, *without individually selecting fields*.

Should return something like this:

| id | fk_table_2 | fk_table_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "foo" | "bar" |

For the moment I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2
ON table_1.fk_table_2 = table_2.id
INNER JOIN table_3
ON table_1.fk_table_3 = table_3.id;
```

which returns all the data I need, but incorrectly structured.
Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using `SELECT *` just choose the columns you would like displayed in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you SELECT everything, but 1 or 2 fields, without writer's cramp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133120/can-you-select-everything-but-1-or-2-fields-without-writers-cramp)

Comment: Unrelated, but: all those parentheses in your query are completely useless

Comment: `SELECT table_1.id, table_2.name, table_3.name  from ....` insted of `SELECT * from ...`

Comment: The important part: *without individually selecting fields*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `SELECT table_2.*, table_3.* FROM ...` does what you want -- if your DBMS supports it -- and is enough to get around your "without individually selecting fields" limitation.

Otherwise, you're saying "I want to individually select fields without individually selecting fields", and that's obviously a contradiction. Why are you subject to such a bizarre restriction, anyhow?

Comment: I am constrained in this way because I am generating these queries with macros. Having to individually select fields is very tedious and error prone. I was thinking of a mechanism similar to a graphql resolver.

Comment: Then you'll have to enhance your macros to generate the select lists that you actually want.