# Select only the rows where column values appear more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select statement similar to the following:

```
select *
from A
  inner join B on A.id_x = B.id_x
  inner join C on B.id_y = C.id_y
  inner join D on C.id_z = D.id_z
where
  A.date > '2014-01-01'
  and A.id_y = 154
  and D.id_t = 2
```

What I want is to do something like this `and count(A.id_x) > 1`, which returns only the parts of the original select which repeat on `A.id_x`.

Is this possible?

EDIT:

I just tried to solve it using temp tables, with the code I got from [T-SQL Insert into table without having to specify every column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573639/t-sql-insert-into-table-without-having-to-specify-every-column)

```
Select * Into 
    #tmpBigTable
    From [YourBigTable]
```

But I got an error message because my tables have the same column names, `A.id_x` and `B.id_x`, for example.

"Column names in each table must be unique."

Is there some way to force the issue, or declare arbitrary naming extensions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from A
  inner join B on A.id_x = B.id_x
  inner join C on B.id_y = C.id_y
  inner join D on C.id_z = D.id_z
where
  A.date > '2014-01-01'
  and A.id_y = 154
  and D.id_t = 2
  AND  A.id_x IN
  (
  SELECT A.id_x FROM A
  GROUP BY A.id_x
  HAVING count(A.id_x)>1);
```

Comment: Thanks.  That seemed to work.  I tried it and kept getting no results (but no error) and thinking something was wrong, until I tested it with `>0`, and realized there were no cases for that particular set of clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with window functions:

```
select *
from (select *, count(*) over (partition by A.id_x) as cnt
      from A inner join
           B
           on A.id_x = B.id_x inner join
           C
           on B.id_y = C.id_y inner join
           D
           on C.id_z = D.id_z
      where A.date > '2014-01-01' and A.id_y = 154 and D.id_t = 2
     ) abcd
where cnt > 1;
```