# SELECT * query, excluding columns

Tags: mysql, select

I have done allot of reading about this and it seems that isn't possible.
The thing is, since the amount of columns is dynamic i cant explicitly mention them. I put in aliases but the 'id' column keeps on appearing.

The `CREATE` doesnt work since there is 3 `id` columns in there, obiously.

(This query actually is ok, it works so dont evaluate it please)

```
CREATE TABLE merged as 
    SELECT *, 
           wuwebusers.id as wuwebusers_id, 
           jgwebusers_address.id as jgwebusers_address_id, 
           jgwebusers.id as jgwebusers_id 
    FROM wuwebusers 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jgwebusers_address ON wuwebusers.id = jgwebusers_address.userid 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN jgwebusers ON wuwebusers.id = jgwebusers.userid 
    GROUP BY wuwebusers.id
```

EDIT:
question: how can i select every column except a few explicit ones. I know SELECT * isn't the correct way, since i am selecting all. I am asking for other way(s).

Since i have to do this a few times and the columns are dynamic and quite a few it isn't maintainable by explicitly writing every column name.

Comment: Do you have a question here?  Don't use `select *` you should always specify what columns you want included in your query.

Comment: Have a look at this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except. Although they do not advise this there is an answer for you

Comment: Try to make it clear what you want help with.

Comment: The amount of columns is dynamic? This is probably a bad idea.

Comment: Are the columns dynamic in every table and how are they dynamic? They do not currently appear to be.

Comment: Lets just say, they arnt dynamic for now, there are just alot of them and when i say alot, i mean A-LOT!

Comment: Script them as `select to` and then copy paste. There are ways around this however with multiple columns being named identically * isn't going to work.

Comment: @Zane: this sounds something to go with.. will give it a try.

Comment: @SanJayFalcon did that fix things for you?

Answer (score 1):

First you are doing a `SELECT *` Then adding columns as well. * is everything therefore you are getting mulitples of the same column. Those 3 ID's that you gave distinct names are being `SELECT`ed again by the `*` in your query. Remove the * and type in the columns you need and you'll be fine.

```
CREATE TABLE merged as 
SELECT 
    wuwebusers.id as wuwebusers_id, 
    jgwebusers_address.id as jgwebusers_address_id, 
    jgwebusers.id as jgwebusers_id , 
    AllotherColumnsYouNeed as WhateverYouWantToCallthem
FROM wuwebusers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jgwebusers_address 
    ON wuwebusers.id = jgwebusers_address.userid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN jgwebusers 
    ON wuwebusers.id = jgwebusers.userid 
    GROUP BY wuwebusers.id
```

/*Edit*\ If you changed your tables to not use the generic method of just labling a column ID in the first place you would also solve this problem. If you have a table name product for example call the ID column for that table ProductID. This will also solve your problem.

Comment: OP states columns are dynamic and cannot explicitly name them. this wont work or at least will not fulfill the requirement.

Comment: Yeah that got added after my answer.

Comment: It was in the original post