# Is it possible to do "like ..." when selecting your column names in SQL?

Tags: sql

So I want to do a simple select like so:

```
select * from table
```

But this table has, for example, 100 columns. I'll only need the columns where "substring" is in the name, like say table has 3 columns: "firstPoints", "secondPoints", "thirdPoints", and then 97 columns without "Points" in the name, is there a way to do a select that only selects the columns that have the substring "Points" in it's name? Like:

```
select * like '%Points%' from table
```

Or something like that, so that, without explicitly passing the columns I want, I still get the select but only of those 3 columns that has "Points" in their name.

Comment: Of course it is possible. Same class as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except. Depending on your RDBMS - dynamic SQL/ polymorphic table functions/trick with JSON/XML.

Comment: First, tag your DBMS. Second, you'll have to use dynamic sql

Comment: No, it is not possible in most databases with a simple `select` statement.  You can do this using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is like this:

```
  SELECT TOP 1000 COLUMN_NAME
  FROM {databasename}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = '{tablename}' and COLUMN_NAME like '%Datum%'
```

This will return a column "COLUMN_NAME" with records of my column names on that table containing "Datum" for example, in my example on my DB it returns 6 column names.