# How to find different rows in two tables with same columns?

Tags: sql

I have two tables that have exact same set of columns. I'd like to select all rows that don't exactly match. Is there a way to do that without joining by every column  or typing every column's name in any other way (I have a large number of them)?

Comment: could you provide some sample data and expect result

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: A proprietary one, not one on the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number, type and order of columns are exactly the same, you can use the `EXCEPT` (or in some DBMS `MINUS`) operator to remove all rows from the first table, that match a row from the second table (by every column).

```
SELECT *
       FROM table1
EXCEPT
SELECT *
       FROM table2;
```

(Use `EXCEPT ALL`, if you don't want or need duplicate elimination. If you want also the result when the operands are interchanged, you can use `UNION` (or `UNION ALL` to union the results of a second `EXCEPT` operation. In doubt use parenthesis to prioritize the operations as needed.)

Answer (score 1):

use `minus`

```
select * from tableA
   minus
   select * from tableB
```

If the query returns no rows then the data is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JOIN` by PK and compare all other columns using:

```
SELECT *
FROM src s
FULL OUTER JOIN trg t
  ON s.id = t.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.col1, s.col2, s.col3, s.col4
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4);
```

Please note that this approach allows to compare data side-by-side.

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=df03903fb9864ec1150c111fa86f2595)**

---

**EDIT:**

> *That still requires to explicitly mention every column? I'd rather not to.*

Yes, but you could use drag and drop from object explorer(SSMS/TOAD/Oracle Developer) and avoid manually typing them.

There is [`SELECT * EXCEPT`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except)(only Google Big Query):

```
SELECT *
FROM src s
FULL OUTER JOIN trg t
  ON s.id = t.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT s.* EXCEPT s.id
                  INTERSECT
                  SELECT t.* EXCEPT t.id);
```

Comment: That still requires to explicitly mention every column? I'd rather not to. I'll edit a question to better state my intention.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Of course there is for instance Google Big Query non standard extension: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49760099/5070879