# How to select all columns except some columns from a database MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Suppose I have a table that contains "200" columns, how do I select all colons except a few, and the way I know is to select it manually:

`"SELECT id, user, name, email, city... FROM table WHERE id = 1";`

However my wish would be something like:

`"SELECT * (exeto essas tabelas) FROM table WHERE id = 1";`

Comment: [SELECT * EXCEPT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413819/select-except)

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can achieve that in MySQL is to use hidden columns (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/invisible-columns.html).