# What is wrong with using SELECT * FROM sometable

Tags: sql, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which is faster/best? SELECT *  or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

I have read the using "SELECT * FROM sometable" is bad practice, esp. if the query is being sent over a network.

Specifically what is wrong with it?