# SQL inner join query returns two identical columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

Let's say I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN department ON employee.EmpID = department.EmpID
```

I wanted to ask, why I am getting two `EmpID` columns, and how can I get only one of those, preferably the first.

I'm using SQL server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT employee.EmpID, employee.name, ...
FROM employee 
INNER JOIN department ON employee.EmpID=department.EmpID
```

Be precise and specify which columns you need instead of using the astrisk to select all columns.

Comment: i should have mentioned it before, i am aware that it works if you specify all the columns you want, but i wondered if there was any other way to get this without specifying all the columns

Answer (score 5):

You get all columns from these two tables, that's why you have two `EmpID` columns. The only `JOIN` type that removes common column is [`NATURAL JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join), which is not implemented by SQL Server. Your query would look then like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee 
NATURAL JOIN department
```

This generates join predicates by comparing all columns with the same name in both tables. The resulting table contains only one column for each pair of equally named columns.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting **all columns** from **all tables** involved in your query since you're asking for it: `SELECT *`

If you want only specific column - you need to specify which ones you want:

```
SELECT e.EmpID, e.Name as 'Employee Name', d.Name AS 'Department Name'
FROM employee e 
INNER JOIN department d ON e.EmpID = d.EmpID
```

Comment: i should have mentioned it before, i am aware that it works if you specify all the columns you want, but i wondered if there was any other way to get this without specifying all the columns

Comment: @user765964: no - either you use `SELECT *` and you get **everything** - or you have to specify **what you want** - there's no other way..

Comment: In general, Crack's comment above provides a more elegant way to do what OP is after, alas, there is no support for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `*`. Specify the columns you want in the field list.

```
SELECT E.EmpID, E.EmpName -- etc 
FROM employee as E
  INNER JOIN department as D
    ON E.EmpID=D.EmpID
```

Comment: i should have mentioned it before, i am aware that it works if you specify all the columns you want, but i wondered if there was any other way to get this without specifying all the columns

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others, don't use `*`

See this SO question for reasons why:

[Which is faster/best? SELECT * or SELECT column1, colum2, column3, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the answer to your question is that the output from a SQL `SELECT` query is not a relation, and therefore if you do not take care you may end up with duplicate attribute names (columns) and rows.

Standard SQL has some constructs to mitigate SQL's non-relational problems e.g. [`NATURAL JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Natural_join) would ensure the result has only one `EmpID` attribute. Sadly, SQL Server does not support this syntax but you can vote for it [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/153679/natural-join-and-using-clause-in-joins).

Therefore, you are forced to write out in long-hand the columns you want, using the table name to qualify which attribute you prefer e.g. `employee.EmpID`.