# mySQL Query - Selecting Fields

Tags: mysql

If I have mySQL table with 10 fields and I only need the to retrieve values of the some fields, is it advisable to use

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3 FROM...
```

rather than

```
SELECT * FROM...
```

I mean does it help retrieval / script execution faster if Im using [SELECT field1, field2, field3....]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, you should query only those fields that you need, as not needed fields will have take up network resourse(transporting from db server to backend server) and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you only want a small selection of fields in a table, it is better to select them rather than pull all the fields back. The difference is not huge but aiming for every optimisation, it may help.

If you have a table with 20 or so fields and want 18 of them, that is where it might be easier/neater to just do a `*` to get them all.

**EDIT**

Further information can be found on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217117/mysql-select-performance) question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should always use the `SELECT field1, field2, field3...` form according to some.

The `*` is ambiguous and I see the point that just automatically selecting every column from a table is lazy although I'm guilty of using it regularly.

From an optimisation point-of-view you should select only the fields you are planning to use also. It may make debugging clearer if you know explicitly what data is being retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

If You Query a `table` with `6800` records having `23 Columns`

With `*` it took Average `0.0009 Sec` in returning  records

And same Query with `5 Columns` took average `0.0005 Sec`

*Tested on `Dual Core Machine 2GB RAM` , `Windows 7` and `Phpmyadmin`*

**Conclusion**

It's always recommended to use required fields despite of `*` where speed is on priority