# how to select those rows where x > y

Tags: php, sql, select, row

Does anyone know how to select those rows where x > y, where x and y both are table columns.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE x > '???' ");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all rows where the column `x` value is greater than that in column `y` it is this simple.

```
SELECT * /*BTW - Don't use *. List desired columns explicitly*/
FROM table 
WHERE x > y;
```

Comment: why not to use *? 
for not to be harder to load?

Comment: @Daniel - Even if you need all columns now using `*` in your queries means that if you add new columns your queries may bring back unneeded data. See for example [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify column names anywhere a value would be valid, even on both sides of a relational operator.

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
  WHERE x > y
```