# MySQL JOIN with results from single table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm looking to join `tableA` with `tableB` to get a series of resulting data.

I need the `JOIN` with `tableA` and `tableB` to ensure I get the correct values from `tableA`, however, I don't want any of the values from `tableB` when I fetch the results.

I appreciate that I can do the following:

`SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3 FROM tableA AS a` etc

I'm looking for a neater way, maybe with some cool new keyword I haven't come across before? (Here's hoping).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Select * is not necessarily a [good way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65512/which-is-faster-best-select-or-select-column1-colum2-column3-etc)

Comment: @Tim Interesting post. Largely unimportant for my project at this stage though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns from table a, just use `a.*`:

```
SELECT a.* FROM tableA AS a etc
```

Comment: Perhaps with `distinct` reserved word?

Answer (score 2):

you can either name out all of your fields:

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3... 
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
    on a.id = b.id
```

or just use you table alias `a.*`

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b
    on a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.* FROM tableA a JOIN tableB b ON a.b_id = b.id;
```